# Adding an artificial row to an anonymous Linq resultset

Tags: linq, insert, addition, anonymous

I'm wondering what the best approach to adding an artificial row to an anonymous linq result set would be.

I have a linq statement which uses "select new" to form the data required. Each record comes back as an anonymous object with ID and Name properties. However, I require that the first row of the data becomes an object with ID = NULL, Name="All".

Is there a way to union in an artificial result into the Linq query? Or else, how do I add a new instance of the anonymous type into the anonymous result collection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the **Concat** method:

```
var q = new[]{ new { ID = null, Name = "All" } }.Concat(dbQuery);
```

Comment: Hi thanks, I'd just come back to post a similiar solution once I worked it out and seen your post.

The thing I was missing was that I hadn't realised I could simply create a new anonymous object instance wih the named Parameters syntax so long as the properties matched.

I ended up using the following to get my row inserted as the first item but the outcomes the same:

anonCollection.Insert(0, new { Name = "All", ID = "" }); 

Thanks.